# Performance issue when calling setRequestedOrientation

Tags: android, performance, fragment

I have vertical android app with many fragments inside just one activity. At some point I'm having user the sign. Thus I rotate device using following code at `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`of signature fragment.

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
```

However, it takes too much time to replace fragment, sometimes more than 2 seconds, and even I put waiting dialog on nextPage button click, It's not showing the dialog. (Even there is no function inside of nextPage button but replace fragment function)

I think It's about CPU, but didn't understand which column (Inclusive Time, Exclusive Time etc) is related to it. Here is screenshot;

[image]

Any idea about solution or what is causing this?

Thanks.